# Reference a table with itself in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, inner-join

I have a question: I have a table with these columns:

```
[idmovimiento] [int] NOT NULL,
[idtipomovimiento] [varchar](250) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[more columns]
[fechamovimiento] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[idmovimientooriginal] [int] NULL
```

Okay, the thing is, some rows have a value in `idmovimientooriginal` which is an `idmovimiento`, I need to create a view which returns the `fechamovimiento` value for this `idmovimiento` saved in `idmovimientooriginal` in some conditions and the `fechamovimiento` for this row if those conditions are not satisfied.

I have tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work...

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN(idtipomovimiento = 'DIG+TRA' AND idmovimientooriginal is not null)
        THEN (SELECT Mov_1.fechamovimiento 
              FROM dbo.MovimientosEstanque AS Mov_1
              INNER JOIN dbo.MovimientosEstanque AS Mov_2 ON Mov_1.idmovimientooriginal = 
Mov_2.idmovimientooriginal 
              WHERE Mov_1.idmovimiento=Mov_2.idmovimientooriginal) 
        ELSE fechamovimiento 
   END AS fechadiagnosticado, 
   [...] 
FROM 
   dbo.MovimientosEstanque 
WHERE 
   [...]
```

All help will be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Try sqlfiddle.com and post a link please.

Comment: It looks to be down sqlfiddle.com :(

Comment: Finally after some time fighting with it I got it:

    CASE WHEN (idtipomovimiento = 'DIG+TRA' AND idmovimientooriginal IS NOT NULL) THEN
                            (select m1.fechamovimiento
       from MovimientosEstanque as m1 
        WHERE     m1.idmovimiento  = MovimientosEstanque.idmovimientooriginal) ELSE fechamovimiento

Comment: Bravo! You can post the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, just in case somebody needs it:

```
CASE WHEN (idtipomovimiento = 'DIG+TRA' AND idmovimientooriginal IS NOT NULL)
THEN (select m1.fechamovimiento from MovimientosEstanque as m1 
WHERE    m1.idmovimiento = MovimientosEstanque.idmovimientooriginal) ELSE fechamovimiento
```